# Derive local minimum from fourth derivative

Tags: calculus

*Question*
Let $I$ be open interval containing $x_0$. $f: I \longrightarrow\mathbb R$ has 4 derivatives and $f^(4)$ is continuous on I.

If $f'$($x_0$)= $f''$($x_0$) = $f^3$($x_0$) = 0 and $f^4$($x_0$) $>$ 0 (zero), show that $f$ has a local minimum at $x_0$.

- So what should I do? It is really hard when it gets complex with more derivatives.

Comment: Why people are downvoting that? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$f^{(4)}>0$ says the tangent has positiv gradient so  $f^{(3)}=mx, m>0 with f^{(3)}(x_0)=0$ than $f^{(2)}=0$ is locally like a positive parabola  so  continue and you arrive at $f(x)=ax^4 locally. More exakt take the Taylorseries at x0

Comment: I did not understand unfortunately.

Comment: Then just write the Taylor series with point x0 .

Answer (score 0):

Expand $f(x)$ at $x=x_0$ by Taylor's formula.

Since $f'(x_0)=f''(x_0)=f'''(x_0)=0,$ hence

$$f(x)-f(x_0)=\frac{f^{(4)}(x_0)+\alpha}{4!}(x-x_0)^4,$$ where $\alpha \to 0$ when $x \to x_0$.
Thus, when $x$ is close sufficiently to $x_0$, $f^{(4)}(x_0)+\alpha$ has the same sign as $f^{(4)}(x_0)$. For such $x$, it holds that
$$f(x)-f(x_0)>0,$$which implies $x_0$ is a local minimum point of $f(x)$.